# Is it safe to ignore rack on Cassandra production machine?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0

I was running an activity of changing rack of nodes, but due to the high volume of data now decommissioning keeps failing for last two pending nodes, so is it recommended to ignore rack for those pending nodes. Long term plan is to add a new data centre and post redistribution of data those pending rack can be updated.

Ignore rack can be done by adding

```
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcassandra.ignore_dc=true"
```

in cassandra-env.sh

Comment: how is it failing

Answer (score 1):

No, especially if you still have other racks your changing what nodes are considered replicas which can lead to data loss. It might be ok if everything else has the same rack or your using simple snitch (which carries other potential issues).

Comment: As of now, there is a single data centre on production so it is using simple snitch and there were different rack id for nodes hence I was bringing them to the same rack. The plan is to create a multiple datacenter and snitch will be GossipingPropertyFileSnitch.